# Upgrade Issues Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I recently upgraded from 11.10 to 12.04, during the upgrade process the computer was hung up on a process and became what seemed to be unresponsive. After waiting about 9 hours for the process to complete with no success, I just turned off the computer.

Probably not the best call and what makes matters worse is I did not backup my data. I have made this mistake before however I was able to boot back up and the old OS was still there and user data was preserved. That was a malfunction that ended up benefitting from in the end, but this time not so lucky. I rebooted and just after the BIOS screen the computer sits at a screen that is just a black screen with a single blinking cursor in the top left corner. Nothing can be typed or commanded.

Is there an OS on the machine anymore?

Is my User data and home folder still available?

Could I just insert by ubuntu 10 disc and re-install... or use without installing... to potentially recover any remaining data??

Answer (score 1):

The old installation should still be there. If you boot from a Live CD, you can probably recover your home folder.